# How to check whether a value in a specific column of a selected row of a JTable is already in a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

My table has a column called "Food Name". I select a specific food item from the table and transfer it to a JList through a button click. I want to restrict transfering of the food item I selected from the JTable to the JList through the button click, if that food item is already existing in the JList.

I have tried comparing the values in the JList and selected food item by using a for loop. I used equals() methos to compare the Strings. But it is always false and the comparision actually doesn't happen

DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
int count = 0;

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int row = foodItemsTable.getSelectedRow();        
    String foodname = foodItemsTable.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();//get the selected food item
    String onlistname = "";

    if(count==0)
    {
       newMenuItemsList.setModel(model);
       model.addElement(foodname+"\n");
    }


        if(count>0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<count+1;i++)
            {
               onlistname = model.getElementAt(i).toString();

                if(!foodname.equals(onlistname))
                {
                     model.addElement(foodname+"\n");
                      break;

                }
            }


        }
        count++;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are iterating over the list of items one by one and then comparing individually.
So it is bound to be always insert the duplicate food items in the list.

Consider in your logic you already have 2 items in your list

1 Apple

2 Orange

Now as per your logic if you have new item as Apple
You condition 
`!foodname.equals(onlistname)` will come to true and it will add Apple again to your list.

Your condition should look to do `.contains()` check on the list to find if already existing.

Go for a `DefaultListModel.toArray()` to get it in array create a `java.util.List` from it and apply `contains()` method to check for already exist logic.

Comment: Should I remove the for loop? 
The problem is with the for loop. The value of 'onlistname' is always the first food item I pass to the JList. It doesn't change

Comment: That's correct use list.contains logic rather than a for loop

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous bugs in the flow of your program. You may want to debug it and remove them first.

If there are no elements in your model, you add it to the listbox and add the element from the table with a newline (why?) to the model.

If there are already elements, you don't add the newline to the foodname prior to the comparision. Since you find a non-matching item immediately, you add the new item again with a newline (making it invisible to your search function).

Effectively, you will always compare only the first entry. If there wasn't the break, you would add the new entry for every element already in the list until it finds itself.

The count is increased even if you find the element (which will never happen, but if you fix the search, then this bug will strike).

Answer (score 0):

When you add your String to the model you are concat it with "\n" but when you compare you don't

as you code is not clear enough i suppose that in your table the food haven't "\n" at end

one simple solution is to trim() the strings before compare

```
if(!foodname.trim().equals(onlistname.trim()))
```

another mistake in your code is that you have a break in your for loop if the value aren't equal

so actually what your code does is check if foodname is equal to  model.getElementAt(i) and if isn't it insert and stop

Comment: I tried using trim(). But it doesn't work. I think there is a problem with the loop